# Test if variable is empty in R

Tags: r

I have a situation where I need to test whether a variable is `factor(0)` but any logical test (including comparing to NULL) I try to assign to it gives `logical(0)`. How do I test if something is an empty factor?

edit: allow me to elaborate.

I have a function and it looks at the attribute of the vector that it takes in, but not every vector has that the attribute, so for vectors that don't have the attribute, when I query the attribute `attr(vector,"attribute")` my return is factor(0) but when I compare that to 0 I get `logical(0)` and comparing it to null or NA also won't work. Any ideas?

Comment: `factor(0)` is not an empty factor. You've created a `factor` of the number zero with one level.... What are you trying to do?

Comment: `identical(x, factor(0))` to test if an object is a `factor` with number zero.  Not sure if that is what you are really looking for though

Comment: I have edited the question hopefully I am being clearer now

Comment: `if (length(x)){...}` will evaluate `...` if and only if `x` is nonempty...

Comment: Are you using the attr function correctly?  I think the problem is you are managing to do something that returns without an error, but isn't returning what you expect. look at '?attr'

Comment: Also note in that when `a = factor(0)`  then `(a=='0')` is true but `(a==0)` is false.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to use `length==0` thanks for the help

Comment: Note that `as.logical(3)` is the same as `as.logical(1)` is the same as `TRUE`, so you don't need to force to logical with `==0` or `==F`. if your `if` statement is simply `if (length(x))` it will still work.

Answer (score 1):

`rlang::is_empty()` also does the job to find if the object is an empty vector or NULL